# Haw to save more than one record for single id in same table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have two tables salary_structures and payheads. Below are my table structures:

```
create_table "payheads", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "company_id",             :null => false
    t.integer  "defined_by",             :null => false
    t.string   "payhead_type"
    t.string   "payhead_name"
    t.string   "under"
    t.string   "affect_net_salary"
    t.string   "name_appear_in_payslip"
    t.string   "use_of_gratuity"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

and:

```
create_table "salary_structures", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "company_id",                                                          :null => false
    t.integer  "for_employee"
    t.integer  "created_by"
    t.date     "effective_from_date"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "payhead_id"
    t.decimal  "amount",              :precision => 18, :scale => 2, :default => 0.0
  end
```

As per my table structure i have payhead_id in my salary_structures table and in my payheads table i have four payheads (basic, Pf etc.). Now when a admin want to define salary_structure of an employee he has to fix amount for every payhead, as per my design i want to save all payheads for an employee for a single salary_structure at once.But here is the problem is for one salary_structure id how can i save more than one  payhead's. Below are my view form:

```
<%= form_for(@salary_structure) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/form_error', :object => @salary_structure %>

        <div class="field">
             <%= f.label :for_employee, :class => "required" %><br />
             <%= collection_select(:salary_structure, :for_employee, @users, :id, :first_name,:autofocus =>"autofocus", :prompt => true) %>
          </div>

     <div class="column width3">
            <div class="field">
             <%= f.label :effective_from_date, :class => "required" %><br />
             <%= f.text_field :effective_from_date %>
          </div>
     </div> 
     <div class="column width6 first">
      <table  class=" display stylized full" id="salary_structure_report" style="">
         <thead>
            <tr>
             <th width="80%"><label class="required">Pay Head</label></th>
             <th width = "20%"><label class="required">Amount</label></th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
             <tbody>
                <% for ph in @payheads %>
                  <tr>
                    <td width = "80%">
                        <%= f.hidden_field "payhead_id", ph.id %>
                        <%= ph.payhead_name %> </td>
                    <td width = "20%" ><%= f.text_field :amount %></td>
                  </tr>
                <% end %>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                   <td class="ta-right" width = "80%">Total</td>
                   <td class="ta-left" width = "20%"><span class="WebRupee">Rs</span><span id = "total">00.00</span></td>
                  </tr>
                 </tfoot>
      </table>
   </div><br />
       <div class = "column width3 first">


              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green big"><img src="/images/add.png" class="icon" /> Save</button>&nbsp;

            <%= link_to 'Cancel', salary_structures_path, :class=>"btn btn-gray bg"%>
       </div>
   </div>  
<% end %>
```

When i tried to save it normally, it does not save payhead id in salary_structures table
, should i have to do something in models. Any help,would be apologize  thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi friends i have found new way to solve it by using an other table  named "line_item" and used a ".build" in my controller and it some how working. In my form i have used nested form.

Answer (score 1):

```
app/models/payhead.rb

  belongs_to :salary_structure

app/models/salary_structure.rb

  has_many :payheads

db/migration/create_payheads.rb

  create_table 'payheads', :force => true do |t|
    # define other columns
    t.integer salary_structure_id
  end

db/migration/create_salary_structure.rb

  # remove t.integer payhead_id
```

access one another by,

```
Payhead.find(some_payhead_id).salary_structure
```

or

```
SalaryStructure.find(some_salary_structure_id).payheads
```

create a new payhead for an existing salary_structure,

```
SalaryStructure.find(some_salary_structure_id).payheads.create(params[:payhead])
# params[:payhead] is part of the form data
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution, but i don't want to save any payhead in payhead table, i want to save a salary_structure with all these payheads and for convenience my amount field is in salary_structure table not in payhead table

Comment: If you don't want to save any payhead in the payhead table, then what exactly do you plan to store in it? Is salary_structure.amount the sum of all payhead.amounts? How do you update it?

Comment: Sir i told earlier my payheads are defined once  the admin for all employee of the company. In salary structure i only save amount for that all respective payheads and i can fetch them from payhead table